# tkinter append button to canvas command

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-canvas

im trying to make command to append/add new button under existing button to open up new windows like blender style gui?

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
#creating frame to basic window, add scrollbar to canvas and background image
class mainWindow:
    def __init__(self, master):
    frame = ttk.Frame(master).pack(fill=X)
    cv = tk.Canvas(frame, scrollregion=(0,0,270,2750), height=2800, width=270, bg = "cyan")
    self.image1 = PhotoImage(file="logoQs270x700.png")
    image = cv.create_image(0, 0, anchor = NW, image=self.image1)
    scb = tk.Scrollbar(frame, command=cv.yview)
    cv.pack(side=LEFT)
    scb.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
    cv.configure(yscrollcommand=scb.set)

    a='white'
    b='purple'
    c=22
    f = 'Neuropol'
    g = GROOVE
    h = 'violet'
    #basic button     
    btn1 = tk.Button(frame, text = "Site Prep", fg = a, anchor = W, font = f)
    btn1.configure(width = c, activebackground = h, relief = g, bg = b)
    btn1_window = cv.create_window(5, 5, anchor=NW, window=btn1)     

#basic window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Built Up Rates')
root.geometry('280x700+0+0')
A=mainWindow(root)
root.mainloop()
```

the idea is to have a several button that act like a title, when click it open
up sub title under it and move the existing button below it downwards
if click the same button again it move up the title button under it and hiding
the sub title or sub labels..
    [logo images][1]
    [blender Gui Sample Not Activated][2]
    [blender Gui Sample When Activated][3]

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pDeu.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUDPb.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPeuA.png
```

Comment: You've told us what yo want, but you haven't asked a question. What part of this problem are you struggling with?

Comment: creating function in existing button to create new desired button underneath and also function to move existing button to desired location

Comment: Is there a reason this has to be on a canvas? It's much easier to do using a frame and pack.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to use a frame rather than a canvas. With a frame you can use `pack`, which excels at stacking widgets top-to-bottom. You don't have to do any calculations in order to place the widgets in the right place.

Each section in your widget should be a frame, and then you simply pack them top to bottom. Within the section you need two widgets: a label for the header, and a frame for the contents. Opening and closing the section simply requires that you call `pack` or `pack_forget` on the inner frame.

### Use an object-oriented approach

Since python is object oriented, you should think of each expandable section as an object. Your GUI as a whole then becomes simply a collection of these objects stacked top-to-bottom. We can create a base class that takes care of the expand/collapse machinery, and the subclasses can add whatever widgets they need to be displayed inside the frame.

### The base class

Let's start with a base class for an expandable frame. We'll create the widget for opening or closing the frame, and we'll create an inner frame to hold the buttons and other things that belong to that frame. We'll add a separator to mimic the look of the screenshots in your question.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk

class ExpandoFrame(tk.Frame):
    closed_glyph = u"\u25b6"
    opened_glyph = u"\u25bc"

    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, borderwidth=0)
        self.title = title

        self.sep = ttk.Separator(self, orient="horizontal")
        self.header = tk.Label(self, width=20, anchor="w")
        self.inner = tk.Frame(self)

        self.sep.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        self.header.pack(fill="x", padx=4)

        self.collapse()

        self.header.bind("<1>", self.toggle)
```

This class will have three methods: one to explicitly expand the section, one to explicitly collapse it, and one to toggle from one to the other.

```
    def toggle(self, event=None):
        if self.closed_glyph in self.header.cget("text"):
            self.expand()
        else:
            self.collapse()

    def expand(self):
        self.header.configure(text="%s %s" % (self.opened_glyph, self.title))
        self.inner.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

    def collapse(self):
        self.header.configure(text="%s %s" % (self.closed_glyph, self.title))
        self.inner.pack_forget()
```

### Subclassing "ExpandoFrame"

That gives us a foundation. Now, each subclass can put whatever widgets it wants in the inner frame. Here are a couple of examples:

```
class SectionSitePrep(ExpandoFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        ExpandoFrame.__init__(self, parent, "Site Preparation")

        self.cb1 = tk.Checkbutton(self.inner, text="Choose this")
        self.cb2 = tk.Checkbutton(self.inner, text="Or this")
        self.cb1.pack(side="top", anchor="w")
        self.cb2.pack(side="top", anchor="w")

class SectionWblff(ExpandoFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        ExpandoFrame.__init__(self, parent, "WBLFF")

        self.rbvar = tk.StringVar(value=1)
        self.rb1 = tk.Radiobutton(self.inner, text="One", variable=self.rbvar, value=1)
        self.rb2 = tk.Radiobutton(self.inner, text="Two", variable=self.rbvar, value=2)
        self.rb3 = tk.Radiobutton(self.inner, text="Three", variable=self.rbvar, value=3)
        self.rb1.pack(side="left")
        self.rb2.pack(side="left")
        self.rb3.pack(side="left")
```

### Putting it all together

Finally, you can put stack these sections top-to-bottom in a frame with `pack`:

```
class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        s1 = SectionSitePrep(self)
        s2 = SectionWblff(self)

        s1.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        s2.pack(side="top", fill="x")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import*

def subT1():

    def destF1a():
        frame1a.destroy()

    frame1a = Frame(frame1)
    frame1a.grid(in_=frame1, row = 0)

    btn1=Button(text = 'Title1', bg = 'yellow', width = w, command=destF1a)
    btn1.grid(in_=frame1a, row = 0)

    btn1a=Button(text = 'Subtitle1', width = w)
    btn1a.grid(in_=frame1a, row = 1)

    btn1b=Button(text = 'Subtitle2', width = w)
    btn1b.grid(in_=frame1a, row = 2,)

def subT2():

    def destF2a():
        frame2a.destroy()

    frame2a = Frame(frame2)
    frame2a.grid(in_=frame2, row = 0)

    btn1=Button(text = 'Title2', bg = 'yellow', width = w, command=destF2a)
    btn1.grid(in_=frame2a, row = 0)

    btn1a=Button(text = 'Subtitle1', width = w)
    btn1a.grid(in_=frame2a, row = 1)

    btn1b=Button(text = 'Subtitle2', width = w)
    btn1b.grid(in_=frame2a, row = 2,)

root = Tk()
w= 23

mainFrame = Frame(root)
mainFrame.pack(fill=X)

frame1 = Frame(mainFrame)
frame1.pack(in_=mainFrame, fill=X)

tt1=Button(text='Title1', width = w ,bg = 'green',command = subT1)
tt1.grid(in_=frame1, row=0)

frame2 = Frame(mainFrame)
frame2.pack(in_=mainFrame, fill=X)

tt2=Button(text='Title2', width = w ,bg = 'green',command = subT2)
tt2.grid(in_=frame2, row=0)

root.mainloop()
```

simple and it works ;) by cheating.. it overlap existing button in same frame and open up new command for the buttons.. using pack, grid, and frame destroy

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import*

def subT1():

    def destF1a():
        frame1a.destroy()

    frame1a = Frame(frame1)
    frame1a.grid(in_=frame1, row = 0)

    btn1=Button(text = 'Title1', bg = 'yellow', width = w, command=destF1a)
    btn1.grid(in_=frame1a, row = 0)

    btn1a=Button(text = 'Subtitle1', width = w)
    btn1a.grid(in_=frame1a, row = 1)

    btn1b=Button(text = 'Subtitle2', width = w)
    btn1b.grid(in_=frame1a, row = 2,)

def subT2():

    def destF2a():
        frame2a.destroy()

    frame2a = Frame(frame2)
    frame2a.grid(in_=frame2, row = 0)

    btn1=Button(text = 'Title2', bg = 'yellow', width = w, command=destF2a)
    btn1.grid(in_=frame2a, row = 0)

    btn1a=Button(text = 'Subtitle3', width = w)
    btn1a.grid(in_=frame2a, row = 1)

    btn1b=Button(text = 'Subtitle4', width = w)
    btn1b.grid(in_=frame2a, row = 2,)

root = Tk()
root.title('Test')
root.geometry('+0+0')
w= 23

mainFrame = Frame(root)
mainFrame.pack(fill=X)

frame1 = Frame(mainFrame)
frame1.pack(in_=mainFrame, fill=X)


tt1=Button(text='Title1', width = w ,bg = 'green',command = subT1)
tt1.grid(in_=frame1, row=0)

frame2 = Frame(mainFrame)
frame2.pack(in_=mainFrame, fill=X)

tt2=Button(text='Title2', width = w ,bg = 'green',command = subT2)
tt2.grid(in_=frame2, row=0)

root.mainloop()
```

this actually works..Expand style tittle.. by cheating.. overlapping technique  existing main button in frame, using pack, grid and frame.destroy() and with new command and thus append desired button :)

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import*
import tkinter as tk

def subT1():
    def destF1a():
        frame1a.destroy()

    frame1a = tk.Frame(frame1)
    frame1a.grid(in_=frame1, row = 0)

    btn1=tk.Button(text = 'Site Preparation', bg = e, width = w,relief = r, fg=d, font = g,command=destF1a)
    btn1.grid(in_=frame1a, row = 0)

    btn1a=tk.Button(text = 'Site Clearence', width = w, bg=f,font = g,relief = s)
    btn1a.grid(in_=frame1a, row = 1)

def subT2():
    def destF2a():
        frame2a.destroy()

    frame2a = tk.Frame(frame2)
    frame2a.grid(in_=frame2, row = 0)

    btn2=tk.Button(text = 'Piling Works', bg = e, width = w,relief = r, fg=d, font = g,command=destF2a)
    btn2.grid(in_=frame2a, row = 0)

    btn2a=tk.Button(text = 'Supply', width = w, font = g,bg=f, relief = s)
    btn2a.grid(in_=frame2a, row = 1)

root=Tk()
root.title('Built Up Rates')
root.geometry("240x600+0+0")
mainCv=Canvas(root,scrollregion= 0,0,225,2750),height=800,width=225,bg='white')
scb=Scrollbar(root,command=mainCv.yview)
mainCv.pack(side=LEFT)
scb.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
mainCv.configure(yscrollcommand=scb.set)

w=25
w1 = 5
r= RIDGE
s= GROOVE
c='purple'
d='white'
e='dark violet'
f='yellow'
g = ('Comic Sans MS', 10, 'bold', 'italic')

mainFrame=tk.Frame(root)
mainFrame_window=mainCv.create_window(5,5,anchor=NW,window=mainFrame)

frame1 = tk.Frame(mainFrame)
frame1.pack(in_=mainFrame, fill=X)

tt1=tk.Button(text='Site Preparation', width = w ,bg = c,fg=d, relief = r, font = g,command = subT1)
tt1.grid(in_=frame1, row=0)

frame2 = tk.Frame(mainFrame)
frame2.pack(in_=mainFrame, fill=X)

tt2=tk.Button(text='Piling Works', width = w ,bg = c,fg=d,relief = r, font = g,command = subT2)
tt2.grid(in_=frame2, row=0)   

root.mainloop()
```

works like a charm on canvas :)